# Isomorphism f:K to L

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Find an isomorphism $f:K \rightarrow L$, which is not the identity function.

$K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5^2)$, $L = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5^3)$

Please help.  I'm lost on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Is that the zeta function?

Comment: Yes. That is all the textbook provides.

Comment: @Alephnull It is presumably not the zeta function; rather, $\zeta_5$ is a primitive fifth root of unity.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Does the 2 denote that it is the 2nd one moving counterclockwise?

Comment: @Alephnull The two is the exponent.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman okay so it is an arbitrary 5th root of unity? Apologies.

Comment: If f is an irreducible polynomial, over Q let's say, then for any two roots a,b of f there is a Q-isomorphism Q(a)→Q(b) which sends a in b.